# Phpmyadmin location for nginx

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

I installed nginx and phpmyadmin. I set up a domain with these parameters to test phpmyadmin:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name example.com;

root /usr/share/phpmyadmin;
index index.php;
fastcgi_index index.php;

location ~ \.php$ {
include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/phpmyadmin$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
}


}
```

And everything works properly (if I visit the domain I can login to phpmyadmin). The problem is that it was just for testing phpmyadmin, now I'd like to move this to my 'default' site. But I can't figure out how to have it on /phpmyadmin. Here's the config for the 'default' nginx site (where I'd like to put this /phpmyadmin location):

```
server {

server_name blabla;

access_log  /var/log/nginx/$host.access.log;
error_log   /var/log/nginx/error.log;

root    /var/www/default;
index   index.php index.html;

location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ index.php;
}  

location ~ \.php$ {
include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
}

### NginX Status
location /nginx_status {
stub_status on;
access_log   off; 
}

### FPM Status
location ~ ^/(status|ping)$ {
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
access_log      off;
}

}
```

Comment: Where are the files for your 'default' site going to be?  If you implement @womble's solution, you will want to make sure you change the `root` under your server block to the location of the files for your 'default' site.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As weird as it seems to sound, the "standard" config did not work for phpMyAdmin on my side.

Here is what I ended up doing, now working with success on "/phpmyadmin" :

```
    location /phpmyadmin {
           root /usr/share/;
           index index.php index.html index.htm;
           location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
                   try_files $uri =404;
                   root /usr/share/;
                   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                   fastcgi_index index.php;
                   fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                   include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
           }
           location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
                   root /usr/share/;
           }
    }
```

I am nowhere a seasoned admin, and this piece of config needs cleaning, but it is a good starter I hope.

Comment: I am redirected from `myserver.com/phpmyadmin` to `localhost/phpmyadmin` with this config.

Comment: Just what I was looking for, great solution!

Comment: I only had to change this line:
`fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;` to `fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;` to overcome **Bad Gateway** issues

Comment: for me it was `fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;`

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing special about phpmyadmin; a standard PHP location block will suffice:

```
location /phpmyadmin {
    root /usr/share/phpmyadmin;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/phpmyadmin$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

Comment: Uhm.. this is what I get going to site/phpmyadmin after using that snippet and reloading nginx config :(

404 Not Found
nginx/1.3.1

Comment: So you've got something wrong.  Fire up the debug log and find out what.

Comment: I have a lot of these:
http://pastebin.com/MKp3b6C5

Comment: Anyone..? :)
Do you need more info?